# How can I parse system hive on Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, hive, registry

My objective is to analyze interest files from windows registries and output useful information.

I already have it for SOFTWARE registers and it worked perfectly, however it doesn't seem to work for SYSTEM registers.

When I apply the same method an error message came up;

> "RAISE PARSE EXCEPTION ( FORMAT NOT SUPPORTED)"

So the problem seems to raise when I declare the system hive and registry variable

In the following code, 'ifind()' method is my own method which allows to ignore case sensitive.

I also show you lines which worked for software registry. 'softhive' and 'softreg' are working but the error is raised on the last line

```
softhive = ifind(os_root + os.sep + 'WINDOWS/system32/config/software')
softreg = Registry.Registry(softhive)

syshive = ifind(os_root + os.sep + 'WINDOWS/system32/config/system')
sysreg = Registry.Registry(syshive) <==
```

Actual result is shown as following in my log:

> Registry.registry Excpetion format not supported

Comment: What is this Registry module? I presume it's from this [python-registry](https://github.com/williballenthin/python-registry) package. You should open an issue with the package developer.